# select all records and the rest

Tags: php, mysql

here is a simple mysqli query to select specific records from my mysql database:

```
foreach ($getData as $data) { {

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `myTable` WHERE `bookid` = '".$data['ID']."' "; 
    $result = $db->query( $sql ); 
                                            
    while ($zeile = $result->fetch_object()) {  
        // DO SOMETHING                         
    }
                        
}
```

The question is:
How can I get (best practices) all the other records, which will not be selected with this query filter?

Comment: Best Practice? `$sql = "SELECT * FROM `myTable` WHERE `bookid` > '19' ";`

Comment: hmmm, bad example. the value 20 is not every time the same. it is a dynamic value

Comment: What's the point of the for loop? Why not do it in SQL?

Comment: You may be better off with using `IN` to fetch all of the records at once, and then use `NOT IN` for the remaining records.

Comment: sorry for the confusion. I updated my first post. the loop is in real a for each loop

Comment: WHERE `bookid` != '".$data['ID']."'  or WHERE 'bookid' != ".$zeile['ID']." in while loop

Comment: yes this will be a possible way. but for this I need a second query. is this the best way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running successive, more or less identical, queries in a loop is fundamentally a bad way to do things. Create a list of `$data['ID']` values you want to work with, then use one query to retrieve all the rows IN that list, and a second query to retrieve everything NOT IN that list:

**Important:** This code assumes that the values in `$getData[]['ID']` can be trusted. i.e. they have been validated before entry to this code, or they come from a trusted source.

```
// Create a list:
$inList = '('.implode(',', array_column($getData, 'ID')).')';

$sqlIn = "SELECT * FROM `myTable` WHERE `bookid` IN $inList";

// run the query. Check for errors
if (($result = $db->query( $sqlIn )) === false) {
    throw new Exception($db->error); 
}
                                            
while ($zeile = $result->fetch_object()) {  
    // DO SOMETHING                         
}
                        
// Now use the same list to exclude those rows

$sqlOut = "SELECT * FROM `myTable` WHERE `bookid` NOT IN $inList";

// run the query. Check for errors
if (($result = $db->query( $sqlOut )) === false) {
    throw new Exception($db->error); 
}
                                            
while ($zeile = $result->fetch_object()) {  
    // DO SOMETHING                         
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It can be like

```
foreach ($getData as $data) { {

     $sql = "SELECT * FROM `myTable` WHERE `bookid` = '".$data['ID']."' "; 
     $result = $db->query( $sql ); 
                                        
      while ($zeile = $result->fetch_object()) {  
            // DO SOMETHING                  
       $query2 = "select * from 'myTable' WHERE 'bookid' != ".$zeile['ID']."'";
       $result2 = $db -> query($query2);
         // do something...       
    }
                    
 }
```

OR

```
 foreach ($getData as $data) { {

     $sql = "SELECT * FROM `myTable` WHERE `bookid` = '".$data['ID']."' "; 
     $result = $db->query( $sql ); 
                                        
      while ($zeile = $result->fetch_object()) {  
            // DO SOMETHING              
      }

    $query2 = "select * from 'myTable' WHERE 'bookid' != '".$data['ID']."'";
    $result2 = $db -> query($query2);
        while($zeile2 = $result2-> fetch_object()){
         // do something...       
    }
                    
 }
```